# confusion from html5 to html compability?

Tags: html

heres my website

http://www.albuquerqueautomotiveservice.com

i think i set this as html5

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

but i wrote it in html

and somethings like the font dont display it just displays as the words of my tags but they have no effect over the content like the & nbsp doesnt work either as you can see on my home button

is there a quick fix to this? like a different doc type or something like that

idk sorry this is my first website and i need help

Comment: Your problems are far more severe than your doctype.  You shouldn't be using `&nbsp;`'s, but you've escaped the `&` and omitted the semicolon. I don't understand how you've avoided tables for layouts but are butchering the content for spacing adjustments.  Here's a laundry list of some issues to address: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.albuquerqueautomotiveservice.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=HTML5&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3

Comment: thanks for that link i didnt know i had so many problems,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To declare HTML 5 the doctype should just be `<!DOCTYPE html>`